# More seasoned than shchi

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> Near a faith's top spots, I'm not quite a sea;
>   I contain water more seasoned than shchi.
>   As you jump in, you will float like a flea.
>   A basketball goat wanders right into me.
>
> Forced into working, and greater I grew.
>   Yet even more so when locked in a zoo.
>   A big city's namesake, that should prove a clue.
>   I'm far from the Near East, and far from dead too.

What am I?

> Yes, shchi is a word.

Hint:

> The answer is the name of a lake.

Hint #2:

> Lines 5-6 refer to ways of deriving the names of two even bigger lakes.

Comment: Can we have another hint? The second part is really tricky

Comment: @Cashbee Added a hint.

Comment: @jafe I love your geography riddles! :D This one was really well-constructed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> [Great Salt Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Salt_Lake)?

Near a faith's top spots, I'm not quite a sea;

> The Mormon faith is centred in Utah, as is Great Salt Lake. It's a big lake - the [33rd largest in the world by area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lakes_by_area).

I contain water more seasoned than shchi.

> It's salty water, and has been called "America's Dead Sea".

As you jump in, you will float like a flea.

> Because it's salty, swimming in the lake is similar to floating.

A basketball goat wanders right into me.

> The [Jordan River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_River_(Utah)) in Utah flows into it.

Forced into working, and greater I grew.

> When you're forced into working you become a SLAVE. This is a reference to the similarly named [Great Slave Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Slave_Lake), in NWT, Canada - bigger than Great Salt Lake as the tenth largest lake in the world.

Yet even more so when locked in a zoo.

> One animal that's locked in a zoo is a BEAR. This is a reference to the also similarly named [Great Bear Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Bear_Lake), in NWT, Canada. It's the largest lake entirely in Canada, and is even bigger than Great Slave Lake as the eighth largest lake in the world.

A big city's namesake, that should prove a clue.

> It's the namesake of Salt Lake City, Utah.

I'm far from the Near East, and far from dead too.

> It's in the US, and it isn't the Dead Sea.

Comment: The answer's correct, but the explanation for lines 5-6 is actually a bit more simple. I have added a hint.

Comment: OOH Canadian reference! Sweeeeet @jafe

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

> Dead sea matches the first 4 lines but I have no clue how to match the second part.

Near a faith's top spots, I'm not quite a sea;

> It's near Jerusalem and it's a lake, not a sea

I contain water more seasoned than shchi.

> It's very salty, more than the sauerkraut based shchi soup

As you jump in, you will float like a flea.

> Allegedly you can walk on it

A basketball goat wanders right into me.

> Jordan is on the east of the lake and Michael Jordan is a basketball Greatest Of All Times (GOAT)

Forced into working, and greater I grew.
Yet even more so when locked in a zoo.
A big city's namesake, that should prove a clue.

> Salt Lake City mabye?

I'm far from the Near East, and far from dead too.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt it's correct, but I have a partial answer for the second half.

> ork

Forced into working, and greater I grew.

> "working" contains "ork"

Yet even more so when locked in a zoo.

> an ork will grow fast with a walking feast around him

A big city's namesake, that should prove a clue.

> Y**ork** / New Y**ork**

I'm far from the Near East, and far from dead too.

> Orks are not native to the Near East (or any non-fictional place) but they aren't dead since they never really lived (they're fictional after all)

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe that El-Guest has the correct answer above; I would like to throw in another possible answer; though it doesn't meet all lines.

> [Mono Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_Lake) in Mono County - California

*Near a faith's top spots, I'm not quite a sea;*

> Couldn't really find an answer for faith here; but it is a lake.

*I contain water more seasoned than shchi.*

> It is a saline soda lake.

*As you jump in, you will float like a flea.*

> As El-Guest stated, this is due to the salt in the water.

*A basketball goat wanders right into me.*

> Basketball Goat could be referring to [Earl Manigault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl_Manigault) (his nickname was literally *The Goat*) who was a big influence on Kareem Abdul-Jabbar of the LA Lakers. However, I like rhsquared's response to this and agree that this refers to Michael Jordan.

*A big city's namesake, that should prove a clue.*

> Mono is a county in California, not a city so it doesn't truly fit here.

*I'm far from the Near East, and far from dead too.*

> It's located in the United States, and it supports aquatic life. Also, as El-Guest stated, it is not the Dead Sea.

**Note**: If you downvote, please leave an explanation as to how I can improve my post. I only added this answer because it was interesting.